# DRF update model with many-to-many field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have two models with many-to-many relationship and I also have nested routers between them.

When I'm trying to create a tag at the endpoint api/page/4/tags/, tag is created in the database for tags, but nothing happend in my table for many to many relationship. How can I fix it?
I want to update my M2M everytime a new tag is created. Thank you

`models.py`

```
class Tag(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class Page(models.Model):
...
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='pages')
```

My `serializers.py`

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Tag
    fields = '__all__'

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

class Meta:
    model = Page
    fields = ['id', 'title', 'uuid', 'description', 'owner', 'is_private', 'tags']
```

`views.py`

```
class PageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Page.objects.all()
serializer_class = PageSerializer

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

```
    class TagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
```

```
class NestedTagViewSet(CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)


    def get_page(self, request, page_pk=None):
        page = get_object_or_404(Page.objects.all(), pk=page_pk)

        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, page)

        return page

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_page(request, page_pk=kwargs['page_pk'])
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tag.objects.filter(pages=self.kwargs['page_pk'])

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_page(request, page_pk=kwargs['page_pk'])
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_nested import routers

from .views import PageViewSet, TagViewSet, NestedTagViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'pages', PageViewSet)


pages_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'pages', lookup='page')
pages_router.register(r'tags', NestedTagViewSet, basename='page-tags')

app_name = 'page'

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include(router.urls)),
    path(r'', include(pages_router.urls)),
]
```

I'm trying to create new tags at the api/ ^pages/(?P<page_pk>[^/.]+)/tags/$ [name='page-tags-list'] host

Comment: what exactly do you want? Do you want to update your M2M everytime a new tag is created?

Comment: yes! For example I created at page/4/tags a new tag named TV. And  my post №4 has to have +1 tag

Comment: which method is called when you access `page/4/tags` ?

Comment: post. and in postman i send title of tag.

Comment: can you add your urls.py?

Comment: There is a problem with logic, and I can't find a solution. After creating a tag i should update my M2M, but I don't know how. I've tried perform update and create, but there were too many errors

Comment: it should be inside your `NestedTagViewSet` do you have the correct page in the `create` method here?

Comment: Yes, I sent a POST request, tag was created. But no changes in M2M table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume after you create a tag you want to add it to the current page in the route.

With this in mind, you have a tag viewset, so you need to override the create method when you are creating a tag.

```py
class TagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        new_tag = Tag.objects.get(id=response["id"])
        page = Page.objects.get(id=kwards["page_pk"])
        page.tags.add(new_tag)
        return response
```

The idea is to create a tag and after you create it, append it to the page M2M relationship. Hope this helps.